# What is the problem when I insert values to a simple table in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I created a simple table in sql-server:

```
create table T1(
a int,
b int,
c char)
```

and when I run this code:

```
insert into T1 values(
(1,1,'A'),
(1,2,'B'),
(1,3,'C'),
(2,4,'D'),
(2,5,'E'),
(3,6,'F')
)
```

I get the exception: **"Incorrect syntax near ','."**
what is the strange mistake??

Comment: You don't need the first and last bracket after values.

Comment: Thanks, Dale K!! you're right! it's works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct statement is:

```
insert into T1 values
(1,1,'A'),
(1,2,'B'),
(1,3,'C'),
(2,4,'D'),
(2,5,'E'),
(3,6,'F')
```

You added 2 “()” too much